# Is it possible to view internal document changes in SharePoint?

Tags: document-library, document, version-history

I am still using WSS

I am still fairly new to administering a SharePoint workspace. I have versioning turned on in my document libraries, but I had a request from a user asking if it was possible to have a view in SharePoint that would show all the internal changes to a document, like what you see with Track Changes turned on when you open a Word document. They want to be able to audit changes without having to actually open the documents, almost like a changes summary view. I realize they can see the version history, but that appears to be only the comments users enter when checking in a version, not the internal document changes the user made.

I have researched, and I don't think it is possible, but before I give an answer I wanted to confirm here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, this isn't possible.

As I see it, no one has made one and it would require some really robust custom coding to utilise this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.trackrevisions

So, the basics of creating one exist, but the actual thing so far doesn't seem to.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I certainly couldn't find anything in all my Googling that presented it as possible, so thanks for confirming. I don't have the permission to write custom code, I just admin one site, so that isn't an option for me right now. Thanks again! (Can't upvote, not enough rep)

Comment: I'm sure someone will make something for this, it's a useful utility.